# Rails: why does activerecord find and find_by_attribute don't behave the same?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I love activerecords multiple `find`:

```
Country.find(1, 2) # Returns an array of countries
```

I love auto `find_by_attribute` generated:

```
Country.find_by_iso2('US') # Equivalent to Country.where(iso2: 'US').first
```

So why the combination doesn't work/exists?

```
Country.find_by_iso2('US', 'CA') 
# Would expect an array, it fails because too many arguments

Country.find_by_iso2(['US', 'CA']) 
# Would expect an array, returns only the last one (Canada)
```

Instead I sadly have to write:

```
['US', 'CA'].map{ |e| Country.find_by_iso2(e) }
```

which is much less elegant.

Answer (score 0):

`Model.find_by(*args)`

Finds the first record matching the specified conditions. There is no implied ordering so if order matters, you should specify it yourself.

If no record is found, returns `nil`.

```
Post.find_by name: 'Spartacus', rating: 4
Post.find_by "published_at < ?", 2.weeks.ago
```

docs: http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods/find_by

Comment: Thanks for replying. Either I don't understand your answer or it doesn't really understand *why* the two methods (`find` and `find_by_attribute`) were not built to behave the same way...

Comment: The `find_by` is going to take the first item that satisfies your parameters, so if I were to, for example query with:

`Post.find_by(name: 'Richard', rating: 10000)`

It's going to return the first item it finds that Satisfies the above. Whereas

`Post.find(name: 'Richard', rating: 10000)`

is going to return all the items within the table which satisfy those column values.

Answer (score 0):

File activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb, line 47

```
def find_by(*args)
  where(*args).take
end
```

Beacuse it accepts an arguments as array and return only first element of it

Comment: Thanks for replying. Either I don't understand your answer or it doesn't really understand *why* the two methods (`find` and `find_by_attribute`) were not built to behave the same way...